# Activity With no UI

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Alright, So I have an application that receives an intent in a Broadcast Receiver, but what I need to do with it, I cant do without extending Activity, so I launch an activity from that receiver, but how can I get it to do what I want it to do, without starting any UI of any kind? Thanks!

Comment: What is it you need to do that can only be done via `Activity`?

Comment: well, getting a string, because SharedPreferences cant be used in `Broadcast Receivers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: Thats what I started looking into, but I'm not sure how to do it, can I launch it one time, then finish it after? like a one-shot thing until the broadcastReceiver starts it again like an activity does?